# Open a file from Google Sheets script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've had a Google Sheets script running for some time (a year) that needs to read an HTML file from it's Google Drive directory. The code to open the file looks like this:

```
var myHtmlFile = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://googledrive.com/host/0B1m........JtZzQ/myfile.htm");
```

... and I could use the HTM file for further parsing.

Suddenly, the code above is throwing an error 404.

Has anything changed recently, stopping me from opening the file?

Answer (score 2):

After a discussion with 'azawaza' (thanks for all the tips), I have finally solved this, so I'm posting the resolution in case others fall into this.

It looks like the construct

```
https://googledrive.com/host/{public_folder_id}/myfile.htm
```

in *UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, true)* can no longer be used. It gives error 404.

I was getting it from the following construct (for simplicity, assuming there is only one parent folder of my spreadsheet):

```
  ...
  var myId = DocsList.getFileById(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId());
  var folderId = myId.getParents()[0].getId();
  var url = "https://googledrive.com/host/" + folderId + "/myfile.htm";

  // url looks like: https://googledrive.com/host/0B1m....JtZzQ/myfile.htm"
  var httpResp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,true);   //throws 404 !!!
  // now, parse 'httpResp'
```

The solution that worked for me, is to find the file directly using this construct (again, assuming there is only one file of given name) :

```
   var htmlCont = DocsList.find("myfile.htm")[0].getContentAsString(); 
   // now, parse htmlCont
```

I don't know why the 'old' solution no longer works. As I mentioned it worked for a year.

**UPDATE (May 2015)**
The 'DocsList' has been deprecated, a new construct:

```
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(myURL);
  if (files.hasNext()) {
    var htmlCont = files.next().getBlob().getDataAsString()
  }
```

has to be used instead

Answer (score 0):

I find it strange that it ever worked before! If it did, it was probably a bug - pretty sure it was never intended to work like that with "local" files... I have never seen it mentioned anywhere that `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` can fetch "local" files like that.

A simple fix would be to just use proper full url of the file:

```
var myHtmlFile = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://googledrive.com/host/{public_folder_id}/myfile.htm");
```

That will ensure your code complies with the API and does not break next time Google changes something.

Comment: I wonder if your script stopping working has to do with forced migration of old sheet (created before Dec 2013) to new sheets, which started today…

Comment: Actually, I screwed up when writing the question, the url param in fetch was the correct url, i.e : "https://googledrive.com/host/0B1m........dQ3U4eDFXNjJtZzQ/myfile.htm", where '0B1m........dQ3U4eDFXNjJtZzQ' is the {public_folder_id} in your answer, so the call was OK. It just quit working today, but it may be intermittent (as many things with Drive). I will re-run it again later and will see.

Comment: Could definitely be just a temporary issue with Drive. If the problem persists beyond a couple of hours, though, it could be something else - try saving a new version of your script and re-deploy it as we app (if it is a web app). If it's a sheet-bound script, try creating a new spreadsheet and copy your script to it to see if it works then.

Comment: Mystery is solved. I was getting the {PublicFolderId} from a construct that involved something like 'var thisFile = DocsList.getFileById(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId())' ... and ... 'thisFile.getParents()[0].getId()' . It looks to me that 'DocsList' is producing IDs, but probably no longer valid ones. Do I remember seeing somewhere it was deprecated?

Comment: DocsList has not been deprecated - at least not yet - but it is an "experimental" service, which means it may be discontinued at any time (like Google discontinued ScriptDb service). In all likelihood, it will probably be replaced by Drive Service eventually. However, back to your issue, - could it be that your file now has multiple parents (for whatever reason) and `thisFile.getParents[0]` no longer points to the public folder, but to some other folder?